# what's the difference between /private/etc/apache2 and /etc/apache2 on mac

Tags: macos, apache2

There are two similar folders in folder systems,files in which folder should I configure?
What's the **difference**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference. From OX X  10.2 onward /etc/* is a symbolic link to /private/etc/*

Comment: @magygt No problem! Don't forget to mark the question answered so others know later :-D

Comment: Well, actually `/etc` is the symlink to `/private/etc`; When you do `ls -l` in root directory, you will see this and several others.